# If the price drops by $20\%$, what will be the effect on demand and revenue?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, economics

The demand equation for a bracelet at a jewellery store is given by $$p= 60 – 0.8q – 0.03q^2$$ for $5 \le q \le 60$, where $p$ is the price and $q$ is the quantity. The original price of the bracelet is $ \$ 32$. Suppose that there is a drop in price by $20\%$. What will the effect on demand and revenue be?

---

So after price drop the new price is $ \$ 32(1-0.2) = \$ 25.6$. Solving $$25.6 = 60 – 0.8q – 0.03q^2$$ gives us $$q = \frac{4\left(\sqrt{745}-10\right)}{3} \approx 23.06$$

The earlier revenue is $\$ 32 * 20 = 640$ and the new revenue is $ 25.6 * 23.06 =590.336$.

According to me: the revenue will decrease by $$\frac{640-590.336}{640}*100 \%.$$

Comment: And what happens when you substitute the new price in the demand equation?

Comment: Yes, your edited post agrees with my math.  Note that at p=32, q=20.  so a 20% drop in price resulted in a demand increase of slightly more that 15%.

Comment: @user2661923 what about the change in revenue?

Comment: $(32 \times 20) - (25.6 \times 23.06) = 49.664$.  Note that in order for revenue to stay constant, the 20% drop in price would have to accompanied by a 20% increase (**exactly**) in demand.  Because of the 2nd term in the function, $-0.03q^2$, decreasing the price by $n$% will result in an increase in demand of **strictly less** than $n$%, so the revenue **must drop**.

Comment: @user2661923 how to calculate the percent of revenue drop?

Comment: @user2661923:  No, if the price drops by $20\%$ the demand would have to increase $25\%$ to keep revenue constant.  $0.8 \cdot 1.25=1$

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it can **not** be calculated directly.  You have to go through the **exact** computations that you showed in your answer, arriving at the change in $q$ from $20$ to $23.06.$  Then, you have to manually calculate the difference re my previous comment, $49.664.$  Then you have to take the percentage of $49.664$ from the base of $(32 \times 20) = 640.$  I see no shortcut to manually computing it in detailed fashion each time.  This is the *price* (ha ha) that you pay for the $-0.03q^2$ term.

Comment: What @RossMillikan commented.  My bad.  The situation is therefore even worse.

Comment: @user2661923 Is the percentage correct what i calculated?

Comment: Yes, your percentage decrease in revenue computation looks good.